# How to add elevation just in the bottom of an element? Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I'm trying to add some elevation or shadow just in the bottom of an element. For this element I'm using a Tab composable. How can I add this elevation/shadow just at the bottom as the image attached?

[image]

If you can see, the Text Field element has shadow around. For this element I add

```
shape = 8.dp,
elevation = 6.dp
```

Inside a Surface element. But I can't use this same attributes in a Tab composable, besides, the shape and elevation adds around all the component, but I just want the "shadow" at the bottom of the Users and Pending users tab.

**For this implementation I'm using Jetpack Compose**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The way your are supposed to add elevation and shadows to elements in Compose is using `Surfaces` as containers for other content.

From `Surface` docs

> Material surface is the central metaphor in material design. Each surface exists at a given elevation, which influences how that piece of surface visually relates to other surfaces and how that surface is modified by tonal variance.

So to add shadow to a tab layout you could do something like this

```
Surface(
    shadowElevation = 9.dp, // play with the elevation values
) {
    Column {
        TabRow(...) // your current TabRow content
    }
}
```

If the above does not provide the desired shadow effect (I needed a stronger shadow) and since you have a rectangular shape anyway you could use a linear gradient instead.

Write a `@Composable` function to make the "shadow"

```
@Composable
fun BottomShadow(alpha: Float = 0.1f, height: Dp = 8.dp) {
    Box(modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(height)
        .background(
            brush = Brush.verticalGradient(
                colors = listOf(
                    Color.Black.copy(alpha = alpha),
                    Color.Transparent,
                )
            )
        )
    )
}
```

Then use it in your existing Compose layout

```
Column {
    TabRow(...) // your current TabRow content

    BottomShadow(alpha = .15f, height = 8.dp) // use higher alpha for a stronger shadow
}
```

Comment: It's strange to wrap the TabRow in a Surface when it is itself a surface, it just doesn't expose the elevation parameter. Perhaps it should

Comment: @darnmason I agree, there are many things Compose should expose or offer out-of-the-box, but it still does not. But even using the Surface and the elevation parameters that are available out-of-the box I can't get the same shadow effects in Compose compared to what Google's MD3 design kit shows for various elevation levels.

Comment: I've also found it painful that compose surfaces don't care about their neighbouring surfaces and will cast a shadow on them even if they have the same elevation. This is contrary to Android views

Answer (score 15):

You can use the modifier `shadow` on your TabRow. Also, add `zIndex` so the shadow is drawn on top of the tab content.

For example, to add the default top app bar elevation you could do:

```
TabRow(
    modifier = modifier
         .shadow(AppBarDefaults.TopAppBarElevation)
         .zIndex(1f),
    ...
)
```

Comment: Why use `AppBar` if the desired element is not in the App Bar?

Answer (score 0):

Inside the surface code, there is the method that you can clone and apply to your Modifier:

```kotlin
private fun Modifier.surface(
    shape: Shape,
    backgroundColor: Color,
    border: BorderStroke?,
    elevation: Dp
) = this
    .shadow(elevation, shape, clip = false)
    .then(if (border != null) Modifier.border(border, shape) else Modifier)
    .background(color = backgroundColor, shape = shape)
    .clip(shape)
```

Then you can apply into your code like:

```kotlin
    Row(
        modifier = modifier
            .surface(
                shape = RectangleShape,
                backgroundColor = backgroundColor,
                border = null,
                elevation = elevation
            )
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .padding(contentPadding)
            .height(56.dp),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.Start,
        verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,
        content = content
    )
```