# Remove elevation from dropdown in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, menu, android-jetpack-compose, elevation

I need remove the elevation/shadow from dropdown menu, like right image:

[image]

My menu:

```
DropdownMenu(
        expanded = mExpanded,
        onDismissRequest = { mExpanded = false },
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(with(LocalDensity.current){mTextFieldSize.width.toDp()})
    ) {
        mCities.forEach { label ->
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                mSelectedText = label
                mExpanded = false
            }) {
                Text(text = label)
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: A snippet of your code can help others give better answers, that match your code.

Answer (score -2):

Based on answer: [How to add elevation just in the bottom of an element? Jetpack Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71801345/how-to-add-elevation-just-in-the-bottom-of-an-element-jetpack-compose) you can wrap your dropdown menu in a Surface and provide the elevation as 0.

Modified code:

```
Surface(
    shadowElevation = 0.dp
){
DropdownMenu(
        expanded = mExpanded,
        onDismissRequest = { mExpanded = false },
        modifier = Modifier
            .width(with(LocalDensity.current){mTextFieldSize.width.toDp()})
    ) {
        mCities.forEach { label ->
            DropdownMenuItem(onClick = {
                mSelectedText = label
                mExpanded = false
            }) {
                Text(text = label)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It dont work for me