# How to Add Elevation to Button? What to Import in Jetpack Compose?

Tags: android, user-interface, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

How to add elevation to button? What to import?

```
@Composable
fun MyUi() {
    Column() {
        Button(onClick = {  }) {
            Text(text = "Lorem")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/71959615/2442831 out?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To add elevation in your `Button` composable, you can pass values to the `elevation` parameter. You can modify your code like below:

```
@Composable
fun MyUi() {
    Column() {
        Button(
            onClick = {  },
            elevation = ButtonDefaults.buttonElevation(
                defaultElevation = 10.dp
            )
        ) {
            Text(text = "Lorem")
        }
    }
}
```

Import `ButtonDefaults` object from `androidx.compose.material3.ButtonDefaults`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ButtonDefaults.elevation()` on Button.

```
Button(
    onClick = { /*TODO*/ },
    elevation = ButtonDefaults.elevation(
        defaultElevation = 2.dp,
        pressedElevation = 8.dp,
        disabledElevation = 0.dp,
        hoveredElevation = 4.dp,
        focusedElevation = 4.dp
    )
) {
    // Button content
}
```

Comment: But what to import?

Comment: @Jorpy import androidx.compose.material.ButtonDefaults to use ButtonDefaults.elevation()

Comment: It gives error "Unresolved reference: elevation"